# Dynamically create elements using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm trying to dynamically create a div block for my slider and it's created whenever the currently playing song changes and i just can't get it to work properly. Also how would you recommend dealing with the song, artist and album names. I realise id means it's unique so only the first block would render correctly and then the other blocks would have no data showing up. Is there a way I can create unique id's for each block in the jquery without it being in the html?

[Here's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oxmX.png)

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="getCurrentTrack">
                      <div id="trackTemplate">
                          <img id="trackimg" width="350" height="350" />
                          <figcaption id="songName"></figcaption>
                          <figcaption id="artistName"></figcaption>
                          <figcaption id="albumName"></figcaption>
                          <img class="invert" id ="add" src="http://indianassist.mx/img/downArrow.png" height="20" width="20" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="getCurrentTrack">
                      <div class="trackTemplate">
                          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/24/28/10/242810087197ad884c0d895c2953a740.jpg" width="350" height="350" />
                          <figcaption id="songName">songName</figcaption>
                          <figcaption id="artistName">songName</figcaption>
                          <figcaption id="albumName">songName</figcaption>
                          <img class="invert" id ="add" src="http://indianassist.mx/img/downArrow.png" height="20" width="20" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="getCurrentTrack">
                      <div class="trackTemplate">
                          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/24/28/10/242810087197ad884c0d895c2953a740.jpg" width="350" height="350" />
                          <figcaption id="songName">songName</figcaption>
                          <figcaption id="artistName">songName</figcaption>
                          <figcaption id="albumName">songName</figcaption>
                          <img class="invert" id ="add" src="http://indianassist.mx/img/downArrow.png" height="20" width="20" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                </div>
```

The JS:

```
var swiperSlide = document.createElement('div');
                            swiperSlide.className = 'swiper-slide';

                            var getCurrentTrack = document.createElement('div');
                            getCurrentTrack.className = 'getCurrentTrack';

                            var trackTemplate = document.createElement('div');
                            trackTemplate.className = 'trackTemplate';

                            var image = document.createElement('img');
                            image.src = jsonPushData.songURL;
                            image.height = 400;
                            image.width =400;

                            var song = document.createElement('figcaption');
                            song.text = jsonPushData.songName;

                            var artist = document.createElement('figcaption');
                            artist.text = jsonPushData.artistName;

                            var album = document.createElement('figcaption');
                            album.text = jsonPushData.albumName;

                            var add = document.createElement('img');
                            add.src = document.getElementById('add').src;

                            trackTemplate.appendChild(image);
                            trackTemplate.appendChild(song);
                            trackTemplate.appendChild(artist);
                            trackTemplate.appendChild(album);
                            trackTemplate.appendChild(add);

                            getCurrentTrack.appendChild(trackTemplate);
                            swiperSlide.appendChild(getCurrentTrack);

                            $('swiper-wrapper').prepend(swiperSlide);
```

I've tried this method aswell `

```
$('swiper-wrapper').prepend($('<div/>', {class: 'swiper-slide'}).append(
                                  $('<div/>', {class: 'getCurrentTrack'}).append(
                                    $('<div/>', {class: 'trackTemplate'}).append(
                                      $('<img/>', {src: jsonPushData.AlbumArt, width: 350, height: 350}),
                                      $('<figcaption/>', {class: songName, text: playbackArray[0].songName}),
                                      $('<figcaption/>', {class: artistName, text: playbackArray[0].artistName}),
                                      $('<figcaption/>', {class: albumName, text: playbackArray[0].albumName}),
                                      $('<img/>', {class: 'invert', src: 'http://indianassist.mx/img/downArrow.png', width: 20, height: 20})))));
```

`

Comment: Use `class` instead of `id`. As for the slider question, I'm not sure what your problem is exactly.

Comment: It's not creating any new elements at all, I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: Are you sure that you're running the code after "swiper-wrapper" has loaded? Do you get any errors?

Comment: GET http://localhost:8888/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found) . I have the swiper wrapper inside an if statement that checks to see if the currently playing song has changed and the code directly after that runs without fault.

Comment: Is `jsonPushData.songURL` a string? Check that it is, because it could be that it is converted into a string in a poor way, making the browser send a GET-request to that weird URL. I may be wrong though, this is just a guess.  What exactly goes wrong? Does it load at all or does the swiper show up in the wrong way?

Comment: I actually chose the wrong tag there it was supposed to be jsonPushData.albumArt. It doesn't load at all. I'm going through the code to see what's going on because that are directly after are running fine.

Comment: ....It should have been $('.swiper-wrapper').prepend(swiperSlide); I forgot the dot!!! Thanks for helping anyway

Comment: +Toby Oh wow, can't believe I missed that too. No problem though! Glad you solved it!